# Can I use my type D visa to travel as a tourist?

Tags: visas, tourist-visas

I am a seaman from Nepal and I have a Italy type D visa valid until Nov 22 2017. I applied for a type C visa recently, but the consulate called me, saying that I can travel to Italy with my valid type D visa. When I went to pick my passport from VFS, a person there told me that I cannot use the type D if I want to go as tourist, and that I have to apply again for the visa type C. The problem now is time. I am travelling in a week. What is correct? Can I travel with the type D visa?

Comment: In general, type D visa holders can travel as tourists, but there might be an endorsement on the visa prohibiting it in your case.  Can you scan an image of your visa, black out any personal information, and add the image to your question?  Also, one should not expect VFS employees to be knowledgeable about visa policies; their role is largely clerical.  The consulate is much more likely to give you correct information on policy matters. Also note that VFS, a business, has a financial interest in your filing a new application, since that will increase their revenue.

Comment: If your application was turned down with the note that you already have a valid visa to travel then what the VFS staff and random people on internet say does not matter.

Comment: The VFS staff are nothing more than glorified couriers. Don't ever listen to what they say.

Comment: Please provide us with a scan of your visa, removing any personal information.